# what's the difference between instantaneous short rate and instantaneous forward rate?

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-processes, forward-rate, short-rate

In the short rate models, sometimes it models the instantaneous short rate and sometimes it models the instantaneous forward rate. Does instantaneous short rate = F(0, t + tau) and instantaneous forward rate =  F(0, t, t + tau)?

Answer (score 3):

In more standard notation the instantaneous forward rate is written as $f(t,T)$, that is, the continuously compounded interest rate seen at $t$ for the infinitesimal interest period $[T,T+dt]\,.$ Heath Jarrow & Morton decided to model those forward rates. Likewise, one can model the *constant maturity* forward rates $f(t,t+\tau)\,.$ These models are very general (almost too general to be useful in practice) and need further specifications. For example: when the volatility of the forward rate $f(t,T)$ is chosen to be $\sigma(t)\exp(-\int_t^T\lambda(s)\,ds)$ you will get the Hull-White model of the short rate $r(t)=f(t,t)$ which satisfies the SDE
$$
dr(t)=\lambda(t)(\theta(t)-r(t))\,dt+\sigma(t)\,dW_t\,.
$$
HJM's work showed that the no arbitrage properties of many interest rate models can be studied under a common framework.